# Reading in parameters for reporter calls in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have two function (reporter) calls in NetLogo:

[ask patches [set p distros [150 140 130 120 110 100 90 80 70 60 50] [4 9 10 13 4 3 2 2 1 1 1]]]

[ask patches [set p distros [150 140 130 120 110 100 90 80 70 60 50] [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 13 10 9 4]]]

that I would like to read in from a CSV file:

150 140 130 120 110 100 90 80 70 60 50

4 9 10 13 4 3 2 2 1 1 1

150 140 130 120 110 100 90 80 70 60 50

1 1 1 2 2 3 4 13 10 9 4

Something like:

[ask patches [set p distros [row1] [row2]]]

[ask patches [set p distros [row3] [row4]]]

Is there an easy way to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

Got it I think. Add the csv extension at the top, then:

```
file-open "/path/to/myfile.csv"
let row1 csv:from-row file-read-line
let row2 csv:from-row file-read-line
let row3 csv:from-row file-read-line
let row4 csv:from-row file-read-line
[ask patches [set p distros row1 row2]]
[ask patches [set p distros row3 row4]]
```

NetLogo should know to remove quote marks when reading in the data.